# creating a NodeJS command line package in Windows

Tags: node.js, command-line-tool

I'm trying to create a command line tool with node (following [these instructions](https://medium.com/netscape/a-guide-to-create-a-nodejs-command-line-package-c2166ad0452e)).

So I add "bin" to package.json file

```
"bin": {
  "say-hello": "./index.js"
}
```

Created index.js file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('Hello');
```

Then I did link

```
npm link
npm WARN part-a@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN part-a@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 5.788s
found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\ka20022276\AppData\Roaming\npm\say-hello ->
C:\Users\ka20022276\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\part-a\index.js

C:\Users\ka20022276\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\part-a -> 
D:\Learning\NodeJS HandsOn\Assignment 2\Part a
```

But throwing error if i use command

```
D:\Learning\NodeJS HandsOn\Assignment 2\Part a>say-hello
'say-hello' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think so. It creates a `.cmd` file and ignore the shebang line

Comment: It comments out in windows but is necessary for npm. It is stated in the article. "In Windows, that line will just be ignored because it will be interpreted as a comment, but it has to be there because npm will read it on a Windows machine when the NodeJS command-line package is being installed."

Comment: @KaranKulwal try `npm i -g ./` instead of `npm link`
https://medium.com/@thatisuday/creating-cli-executable-global-npm-module-5ef734febe32

Answer (score 0):

So i tried the example as you mentioned myself a while ago and had the same error. I searched for a while and found the solution. Basicly you have to add a path for this to work.

After you use `npm link` a `say-hello` & `say-hello.cmd` file is created here `C:\Users\ka20022276\AppData\Roaming\npm` on your computer.

You have to include that `path` to your `system variables`.

Goto: `Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables`.

In the `System Variables Window` find `path` and click on `edit`.

In the `Edit environment variable Window` click `new`, `paste` the `path` and click `ok`.

After following these steps you have to re-open your editor and try again.